# How to add shadows to a popover that implements a UIPopoverBackgroundView

Tags: ios, ios5

According to Apple's documentation, a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView implementation should not contain shadows, but those don't seem to be provided elsewhere either.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html

> Note: The images you use for your popover background view should
>   not contain any shadow effects. The popover controller adds a shadow
>   to the popover for you.

The UIPopoverBackgroundView implementation: https://gist.github.com/1489041

Comment: Right in the title: How to add shadows to a popover that implements a UIPopoverBackgroundView

Comment: You should write it in the question body too.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the shadows should be part of your background image you are using when subclassing the UIPopoverBackgroundView. The shadows mentioned in Apple's documentation note seems to apply to the view contained in your popover. At least this is what i experimented.

Comment: Your suggestion contradicts official documentation.

Comment: I see two type of shadows when you display a default popover: the one outside of your content view (ouside the border of your popover) and the one apply to your content view. Which one is referencing the official documentation then? I don't see any shadow apply outside the popover per default if you don't provide a shadow effect to your background image.